# Use lookup-formula in every cell of a column (without dragging it)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

[image: spreadsheet-image showing lookup-formula]

I want to use a `VLookup` formula for every cell in a column (German=sverweis). The `VLookup` range always stays the same, but the value (m3, m4, m5) has to change in every cell.

Since I use a form, new records always come in and therefore dragging the formula down is not a good idea. The formula is running in every cell of column N.

I tried to use the array-formula, but somehow I got stuck.

Do you know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turn the range into a list (Insert - Table) so that the formula is automatically dragged down when new records appear?

Comment: That would be my answer but it looks like he's using google sheets.  I have a script that puts the edit link into the sheet when the form is submitted and I modified it to add a couple of formulas at the same time.  I'll see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick using a script that puts an edit link into your form responses sheet.  You'll see at the bottom I added a couple of simple formulas to add 2 cells together `sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+2).setValue('=B'+intRow+'+C'+intRow);` This is where you can put your vlookup formula.

You need to change YOUR-FORM-ID to the long form ID from the URL of your form.  I had trouble with this as Google now hides your ID on the user facing form so you need to go to the form editor and copy the ID from there.

You will also have to change the sheet name in the code to match yours.

```
// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/YOUR-FORM-ID/viewform';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column,
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      Var intRow = i + 1
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+2).setValue('=B'+intRow+'+C'+intRow);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+3).setValue('=H'+intRow+'+E'+intRow);
    }
  }
}
```

If you're not familiar with the script editor you just click on tools and script editor and then replace the whatever code is there with this code.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Wow, you are my Champion! Thanks a lot! I'll check and come back!

Comment: I just noticed that the code uses a variable called columnName to automatically find the correct column to update.  You could change that to eMail and then put your vlookup where they have the editResponseUrl.